# How to fetch the response from my Django view & url and console.log the response in my Django template (home.html) using Javascript

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to console.log the Json(response) from my View in my home.html template with no success.  Here is my code:

**Views.py**

```
def Tweets_view(request, *arg, **kwargs):
    qs = Tweets.objects.all()

    for x in qs:
        tweet_list = { 'id': x.id, 'content': x.content }
        context = { 'response': tweet_list }

    return JsonResponse(context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from tweets.views import Tweets_view_id, Tweets_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('tweets', Tweets_view),            #N.B This is the URL I'm trying to access.
    path('tweets/<int:tweet_id>', Tweets_view_id)
]
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends './base.html' %}

{% block content% }
    <div id="tweets">
        LOADING ...
    </div>

    <script>
        
        const tweetsElement = document.getElementById("tweets")
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        const method = "post"
        const url = "/tweets"
        const responseType = "json"

        xhr.responseType = responseType
        xhr.open(method, url)
        xhr.onload = function () {
            const serverResponse = xhr.response
            var listedItems = serverResponse.response
            console.log(listedItems)
        }

        xhr.send()

    </script>
{% endblock content% }
```

**my browser (Displays nothing in the console)**

[This is the link to the my browser display image. No data displays in my console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUAAq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put a console.log to see if you enter your function `xhr.onload` right before `const serverResponse`.

And try changing your
`const serverResponse = xhr.response`
to
`const serverResponse = this.response`

(console.log both to see what happens).

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Utiliser_XMLHttpRequest)